# Adding D3 usmap v3 to React

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to add a D3 us map via React in v3 and stuck on this error.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'defer' of undefined (in the queue() method)

the code works great in v4 when the d3.queue() is added.

```
//package 
"d3": "^3.5.17",
"queue": "^1.0.2",
"topojson": "^1.6.27"

//offending code snippet
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import queue from 'queue';
import * as topojson from 'topojson';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import './map1.css';

class Map1 extends Component {
    state = {
        usData: null,
        usCongress: null
    }

componentWillMount() {
    queue()
      .defer(d3.json, "/data/us.json")
      .defer(d3.json, "/data/congressional-districts.json")
      .await((error, usData, usCongress) => {
        console.log('us.json', usData);
        console.log('us.congress', usCongress);
          this.setState({
              usData,
              usCongress
          });
      })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you confused the package [`d3-queue`](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue) with [`queue`](https://github.com/jessetane/queue) which is something totally different.